# Unable to resolve Grub Rescue issue on Ubuntu despite a lot of research

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have Windows 7 home premium 64 bit installed on my Dell laptop. Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a VMware instance to learn Hadoop. I am getting Grub Rescue (normal.mod not found) as shown below whenever I power on Ubuntu on VMware.

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

I have gone through a lot of posts regarding this issue on Google, SO and watched many videos on YouTube as well but I am not able to resolve this error. Please see below the steps I have followed:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)
(hd0,msdos5): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is ext2.
```

So (hd0,msdos1) is the correct partition to look for in my case.

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ VMware-uid-0/ dev/ proc/ run/ sys/ usr
```

As you can see, boot folder is completely missing. However, I could find i386-pc folder inside /usr/lib/grub

```
grub rescue> ls /usr/lib
This led to a lot of folders where I found grub which has i386-pc folder.
```

Finally when I enter

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/usr/lib/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

This is taking me to **Grub** screen from **grub rescue** screen. What steps do I need to follow next. Please guide me on this. Please let me know if more information is required from my end.

Note - I have also seen videos regarding rebooting Ubuntu using a pendrive to resolve this issue but unfortunately could not understand much.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my Dell Latitude I reinstall ubuntu with boot partition them miracle it work. Your partition table table should like this

- Boot 1- 10 GB
- / Root (I have put 120)
- Swap Just little bit more than your RAM
- Home Partion

Answer (score 0):

Importnat : Please read the full post from top to bottom.

1.Grub Rescue error generally occurred when we deleted the Linux /ubuntu partition from our system.

when we restart our system the grub rescue error is occurred first we  have try this following approach to resolve this problem

A.     grub rescue> ls

(hd0) (hd0,msdos5)

(hd0,msdos1) (fd0)

grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)

(hd0,msdos5): Filesystem is unknown.

grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)

(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is ext2.

we check all the partition and found in which partition is showing the "Filesystem is ext2.".

now follow the step B.

B. grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/usr/lib/grub

grub rescue> insmod normal

grub rescue> normal

Important:-Here "hd0" id the partition name  in which we have "Filesystem is ext2."

```
if problem is solved then pretty well ,Otherwise go to in step 2.
```

2.if in above step "A" you have not found any partition which having the "Filesystem is

ext2." then follow the

A. take a pendrive up to  8 GB capacity

B. make it bootable.(if using ubuntu no need to make bootable)

C.HOW TO GET AND USE THE DISK:

(1) DOWNLOAD BOOT-REPAIR-DISK, link :https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download

(2) Then burn it on a live-USB key via Rufus or Unetbootin . (do not burn it on CD/DVD if your PC came with Windows8/10)(if you are using ubuntu no need to make bootable to pendrive)

(3) Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC,

(4) Choose your language,

(5) Connect internet if possible

(6) Click "Recommended repair"

(7) Reboot the pc -->
the issue will resolve.
thanks for reading the post.

if issue again persist then please ask me again.
I will  definitely answer you.

Answer (score 0):

**IT WORKED FOR ME UST FOLLOW ALONG**
i know its little old to answer this now...

find the whole tutorial in my git account link

https://github.com/katilalloyd/fixing-error-file-normal.mad-not-found-entering-grub-rescue-stack-overflow

STEP 1 : **try to get into grub**
do this
uset `set` to locate where grub is installed in your case it would be msdos1 partition

STEP 2 :**set root and prefix**

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
```

then type:

set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/usr/lib/grub

STEP 3 :**TRY  insmod**

```
insmod normal
```

this should not give out an error .If so reset the root partition or use the ls to find the ext4* partition

STEP 4:**ENTER GRUB**
type the normal command to enter grub

```
normal
```

*DONT FORGET YOUR EXT4 PARTITION*

STEP 5 : **Find the ;lost and found files**

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)
```

atleast your output should begin with "lost+found" and contain /boot/ and /etc/

STEP 6: **List the vm and intrd**

```
ls -l (hd0,msdos1)/boot
```

note the vmlinuz
in my case it was "vmlinuz-5.15.0-kali.0amd......."not really sure

**NOTE   FOR GPT USERS vmlinz might contain generic**

PICK THE LAST vmlinuz in the list if you have multiple

ALSO NOTE "initrd.img....." code name**

STEP 7 : **SET ROOT **

```
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
```

STEP 8 : **SET vmlinuz and intrd**

```
linux /boot/**enter here your vmlinuz name code then one space**  root=/dev/sda1
```

#**for hd1 users use sdb
hd2 users use sdc
hd3 users use sdc
**

next set the initrd

```
initrd /boot/**initrd.....ENTER YOUR INITRD CODE NAME
```

**
if you recorded no errors  then you are almost done easy right!!!

```
boot
```

system should boot successfully

FINAL: **UPDATE & INSTALL GRUB**
press

> ctr +alt + t
> to the terminal enter :

```
sudo update-grub2
```

> install grub

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
```

wallah
reboot and see the magic

find the whole tutorial in my git account link

https://github.com/katilalloyd/fixing-error-file-normal.mad-not-found-entering-grub-rescue-stack-overflow